# Common Strategic Junction Types in Topology / Topologizing?

Tags: faces, topology

**Is there a common group of junction types a re topology-artist should be aware of?**

---

Explanation of question:

It seems I've been thrust into the world of re-topology now that I am making more use of zbrush.

I noticed there are many times when mesh-density changes should occur either upward or downward depending on detail. I also avoid using tris, which means more puzzling situations: How to scale / decrease density without using tris?

The whole issue boils down to this: **Face Junction types**.

Perhaps this is a naive assumption or oversimplifiction, but I wonder if there exists **a small visual reference of common junction** types used in topology. A certain 'holy grail' or reliable catalog of junction types, possibly named, and explained?

As I'm very new to this, I've attached a screenshot of one I commonly use in downscaling or upscaling mesh density, but I'm sure I could be using different approaches / face arrangements.

[image]

Comment: If it is ok on stackexchange, I'd like to have a quick critique on this region of topology as an added note, since it reflects my model as a whole.

Comment: The strategy isn't that simple of just modeling by using 4-sided polys, but using 4-sided polys *and* keeping them not distorted too much. Take a look at [this modeling blog](http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/). Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/when-are-tris-used-effectively, also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28425/curved-mesh-topology