# Edged and plain faces?

Tags: modeling, faces

So I've never done it but now that I see other models with it everywhere I wonder why? I included pictures because I'm bad at describing things. (This is also why I ask here, I don't know what terms I'd search for)

-Is it needed or recommended to use edged faces? If so, please explain what you'd use them for in modeling or animating.

Plain Face
[image]

Edged Face
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/when-are-tris-used-effectively, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-tris?lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36270/how-can-tris-be-used-to-an-advantage. Could possibly be a dupe of one or two of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quads are not always necessary, but are usually preferred when deforming a mesh for animation &/OR Rigging. If you are creating a static model (eg. a sculpture of a statue, etc...) Then it can be acceptable to use Triangulated faces, as there is no reason to worry about the integrity of the deformations.

Notice the deformation smoothness when we bend a cylinder.
[image]

[image]

**As for my version of face Definitions:**

NGon technically a face with vertices > 3, but because we have names for 3 vert, and 4 vert faces, this is commonly reserved to describe a face >= 5.

Quad = 4 vertices.

Triangulated is just the primitive minimum for a face to exist, as the vertices that make it up = 3.

Two vertices make an edge with no area.

One is just a single point (Vertex).

Comment: Alright, so plain aka Quad faces for animated models and edged aka Triangulated faces for non-animated models. Thanks Rick Riggs! *Edit: Also, thanks for the picture examples!*