# How to join vertices to edge

Tags: modeling, mesh

The vertices does not join to the edge so a gap is form. The thing is I do not want to create a new face to fill the hole because I want my mesh to be quad. How do I fill the hole while keeping things the same?[image]

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to keep things the same *and* leave the model as all-quads. To follow first you'll use Ngons. To follow second you'll increase amount of faces. Both ways have their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: im going to sculpt and 3D print the model. Which one do u suggest? First or second? Please explain how to i approach it too. Thank you!

Comment: If you are going to sculpt that, hence subdividing first, it's best to stay with quads only. They will provide you with expected results once subdivided. You can *try* do that with Ngons, but beware that if something happens undesired most likely you'll need to redo model topology and at least part of sculpting. See also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they

Comment: ohh.. interesting i have already subdivide and stay with quad throughout the model. How would u suggest to fill the mesh?

Answer (score 2):

If you want only minimal changes, you can just snap the vertex to the edge. It is "messy" from a topology point of view but you will basically get what you want. (As long as you don't use any modifiers)

The quality way would be to add an edgeloop to the quads shown on the right (split each quad into two) and connect the vertex to the end of the edgeloop:

[image]

Comment: I have subdivision it before, so i dont think its okay to use edge loop. Will knife do the job? That is a quad. Although it look messy, i try to keep it as all quad because this is how i started out with. Im going to 3D print the model, will ngon, quad or triangular affect the result?

Comment: 1. So I do understand you correctly, you still have to subdivide the mesh after the model is finished?   2. from a topology point of view the result of a knife or edgeloop will be the same, so I do not quite understand this argument 3. afaik ngon is internally just a lot of triangles 4. I don't think there is a good argument to "stay with quads because it was originally  a cube"

Comment: no i wont be subdividing it again. ohhh.. i see. This is my first time using blender so there is many thing im still learning. i suggest knife is to minimize the number of face since edge loop go around the whole model while knife can divide the necessary face. i remember i saw an article that say quad is the best way to go in many thing. There is many debates in it. but since im new, i thought i should go the safest way hahaha

Comment: @niki - 3D printing is one of those things that this battle over Tri's/Quads shouldn't really matter. Most of the time these things get converted into and STL file anyway (which is Triangulated faces). ngons can cause some grief however, especially in a situation such as 3D Printing. The biggest reason to keep the Quad's is for mesh deformation when you will change a pose of your mesh. [Related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/edged-and-plain-faces/48250#48250)

Comment: @niki - I don't want to persuade you to not pursue good topology using Quad's, because it is good practice for modelling, however there are times to not sweat it., I venture to say that this is one of them.