# How to plan meshes - topography

Tags: mesh, topology

I am just starting 3D modeling and I am having a bit of trouble planning my meshes so that they flow well and are built in a way that supports the model.

I keep running into "trouble spots" where my meshes kink, pinch, or twist up. I have been unable to find resources that explain the best places for loops/cuts/etc.

I understand it will be dependent upon the model, but I would like to know the best way to plan the flow of meshes and deal with common situations.

Comment: This is a tough subject, and it has some differing approaches to it. My best advice to you is to play with your bending points, and play with different NGONs. Quads are usually preferred in animation, as the deformations are usually controllable [See THIS LINK](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/edged-and-plain-faces/48250#48250) for more info.

Comment: I consider this to be one of the best topology and modeling "good practices" compendium http://topologyguides.com/