# Why using Star like tris?

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

[image]

[image]

What is the benefit and utility of this use of star-like Triss?What are the rules of this type of institution?

Why is it used?

And why is it done that way and not that way?

I would appreciate if there is a source, it will be in the course or video I can learn. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are tris used effectively?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/when-are-tris-used-effectively)

Comment: I wonder if you have a source that tells you to use tris like this and says there are benefits and it has to be done this way... I only know sites where they infinitely repeat the mantra that you should always only use quads.

Comment: the topology of the second image is super dirty but as long as it looks good in render why worry? As for the first picture, using tris allow you to quickly reduce the topology, same thing, if the render looks ok, it's ok to use tris

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it used?

Chiefly, because it is easily automated. This kind of topology is most often the result of automation; Booleans. where the intersection between surfaces is programatically calculated, or automatic conversion from other data-formats.

> What is the benefit and utility?

Apart from the above, none in particular.

There *can* be disadvantages.

- If modelling by hand, the topology does not play well with polygonal modelling systems, including Blender, that are geared to the selection and manipulation of loops and rings of edges bounding 'tracks' of quadrilateral faces.
- The reason quads are emphasized is that, if  quad face-loops flow across polygonal surfaces in a way that echoes an underlying approximated curvature, then when they are triangulated by a renderer, and the normals are interpolated by a smooth-shading algorithm, the normals approximate those of the smooth curved surface more accurately. Especially under Catmull-Clark subdivision, which is a common modelling target.
- Correctly flowing quad face-loops deform well, where that is called for, by animation or subsequent modelling techniques. There are no unexpected creases or kinks in deformed surfaces.

Wherever surfaces do *not* have to be accurately smooth-shaded, either in their modelled form, or under subsequent deformation, (because they are geometrically flat, or shaded flat,) there is no great harm in non-quad topology, but for ease of modelling, you may choose to avoid it. If a curvature is more accurately approximated by sheer density of polygons, the computational cost may be high, but the question becomes less relevant.